# How to save Excel file as CSV, without losing long text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file I want to save as a CSV. Some of the cells has a lot of data in it, and so Excel shows it as

```
##############
```

And the sort. But of course, the data is actually there.

But when I save it as a CSV, it actually overwrites the data in those cells with those #######

And thus I lose data. How can I fix this, so it doesn't overwrite data with ######?

Double-clicking the cell length to widen it does not work, as the cell is so large even Excel doesn't expand it long enough. Expanding the rows and/or columns did not help either, still showing up as ###### because there's not enough room to display it on the screen/cell.

Comment: The Text property of a cell is it's displayed value. The Value property is the underlying data. Sounds like your using code accessing the Text property to output a CSV file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue may be that you have a Text format applied to the offending cells.  In an Excel cell with Text format, there is a [limit](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx) of 1,024 characters.  For example, the two cells below contain the same text, but `A1` is formatted as General and `B1` is formatted as Text. When saved as CSV, `B1` is saved as pound signs.

[image]

Try removing the text format if it is not absolutely necessary to presenting the data properly, and then saving as a CSV.  That should do the trick.

If you have long data that needs the Text format to keep Excel from changing your data (e.g. a long sequence of numbers with leading zeroes), you can enter an apostrophe before the text in the formula bar and then convert the cell format to General.

Comment: The link above is specifically for Excel 2003.  Here are the specs for Excel 2007: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx
Although it is not specified here, Excel 2007 also has the same character limit on Text-formatted cells.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution, but use Ctrl+A to select all columns, double click a column separator to make it expand to the size to fit the cell contents, then save the csv, and ctrl+z to undo the column expansion?

Comment: The cell is too long to do that, it still expands but not the full length of the cell (there's paragraphs of data) and still shows up as ######

Comment: Can you also expand the rows?

Comment: I tried, still didn't give enough room. The data is an export of SQL from a content website, and this field is the content.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try expanding the width of the column containing the data, to eliminate the `######` before saving as a CSV.